# How to get web server log file?

Tags: hadoop

I want to work on web server log using apache hadoop. But I am not able to find sample dataset. Can anybody help me with the links?

Regards,
Bhavani

Answer (score 0):

some of the sites.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381806/large-public-datasets
http://aws.amazon.com/datasets
http://commoncrawl.org/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674421/free-large-datasets-to-experiment-with-hadoop
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843892/download-large-data-for-hadoop

all the best..
```